# Backbone, keep a models data even after the page was refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am building a REST API.

Client side, I use Backbone.

Upon authentication, the API sends a token via ajax over to Backbone's Session model.

I place that token using jQuery's ajaxPrefilter method, to be send back the token towards the API on every request.

Everything works perfect, until the users refreshes the page.

If the page is refreshed, the token is lost, the model re-initializes and the user has to authenticate again.

How can I bypass this?
1. Store the token inside a cookie (very unsafe, bad idea) - defeats the REST purpose.
2. Store the token inside LocalStorage - equally bad, I believe.

Is there something else that can be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the token both ways.

If you're using ssl, the token is only available to the client (and NSA, maybe) which brings no problem.

I rather store those token using localStorage unless the client doesn't supports it.

You can also check this answer 
[Keep Session Across Page Reload In Backbone JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710837/keep-session-across-page-reload-in-backbone-js?rq=1)

Comment: I will retrieve the token from my API via SSL - https://myapi.com - but once it reaches the client and will be stored in local storage? Not sure I see where the SSL comes in... in that stage

Comment: Without ssl, the token would be unsafe. Now, storing them in localStorage it's not. The user would always get to know it so he can make requests.